# how to resize a div from inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, wrapped in an object:

```
var obj = {
   resizable : function(element, size) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
            element.style.width = parseInt(size) + "px";
        });
    }
}
```

and it does not resize the `div` tag when I call it like this:

```
obj.resizable(wrapper, window.innerWidth/2);
```

When the event listener is outside of my function it works.
Any idea how to make it work using the code snippet above?

I don't want to use any libraries, so please don't suggest anything with Jquery.

Comment: you're not resizing, you're adding a listener to know when you're window will be resized. Just do function(element, size){element.style.width = size + "px";}. Furthermore you concant size with px, there is no need of parseInt so. If you start in javascript and not doing this per entertainment, like a project for a client, go with frameworks or you won't make it.

Answer (score 0):

This will immediately resize your element (happens once, or every time you call this function):

```
var obj = {
   resizable : function(element, size) {
            element.style.width = size + "px";
    }
}
```

---

This will add an event listener, so whenever you resize  your window the `function(event){...}` part will be called.

When you add an event listener to X element, it does ***not immediately*** resize your element as you had intended. It only gets "triggered" when that event occurs. Since you specified "resize", then it gets "triggered" when a "resize" occurs.

```
var obj = {
   resizable : function(element, size) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
            element.style.width = parseInt(size) + "px";
        });
    }
}
```

Additionally like Walfrat (in the comments) mentioned, you do not need to `parseInt` `size`.